# Adb says -> USB DEVICE NOT FOUND

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I have bought in Italy a tablet **Mediacom  SmartPad 7.0** model **M-MP720GO**.

I'm trying to develop an android app but i'm not able using it.
When i try to start my ide (IntelliJ-Idea 13) in debug mode i have this error : 
**"USB DEVICE NOT FOUND**

My developing enviroment is  IntelliJ-Idea 13 with Windows 7 , jdk 1.6 and Android SDk release 22.6.2

I can't download neither on the site neither from the package the driver for this device.
I have tried using other android devices and i've seen that  the debug mode for developer works perfectly.
Please can you tell me how i should use it and if someone has done with success a debug mode on this device ?

Regards

Nik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will have to modify the adb_usb.ini

http://delendanet.blogspot.de/2012/11/mediacom-101s2-collegarsi-in-adb.html

Comment: Great,great!!
Now, it works perfectly
Thank you  so much!!!